# Displaying all Many to Many relationships in one template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, many-to-many

I am writing a todo list application for myself as well as a way to better familiarize myself with Django and all it's painful intricacies.

I am trying to use a many-to-many relationship between List models and Item models such that an item can be present in one or more lists at a time.

Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime

def makeName():
    return datetime.now()

# Create your models here.
class List(models.Model):
    #owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    canView = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='user')
    listName = models.CharField(default=makeName, max_length=100)


class Item(models.Model):
    list = models.ManyToManyField(List, blank=True)
    field = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date Made', auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
{%  if lists %}
    <table>
    {% for list in lists %}
        <!--{{ list }}
        {{ list.item_set.all }}-->
        {% for item in list.item_set.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.field }}</td>
            </tr>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{%  else %}
    Woops, you don't have any lists. Consider adding one.
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import List, Item
from .forms import ItemForm
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
# Create your views here.

def getLists(request):
    lists = List.objects.filter(canView__user__id=request.user.id).values('listName')
    temp2 = dict()
    for list in lists:
        temp = list.get('listName')
        temp2[temp] = List.objects.get(listName=temp)
    return temp2


@login_required
def index(request):
    lists = dict()
    lists = getLists(request)
    list = lists['MainList']
    print(list.item_set.get(pk=1))
    print(lists['MainList'].item_set.count())
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'lists': lists})
```

So my issue seems to lie in index.html. I am trying to display every item in every list all on one page. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755380/displaying-reverse-many-to-many-in-django-templates) question of a semi-similar degree basically said, iterate over list.item_set.all but when I do that, I don't get any output. I do have items populating the database and when I print from the view to the console I do see the values I expect. Any advice and/or guidance would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getLists` function returns a dict, mapping list names to lists. So when you iterate over `lists` in the template, you're iterating over that dict: and iterating over a list just gives the key, which here is the list name.

If you want to test iterating over many-to-many items, you should simplify your code; remove that getLists function altogether and just return the lists.

```
def index(request):
    lists = List.objects.filter(canView__user__id=request.user.id)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'lists': lists})
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't stop to think about the dictionary when it came  to iterating over it. Thanks for the help!